# RAILS_ENV changing the content of app/layouts/application.html.erb content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm working on a rails app, and have recently moved the `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` line of `app/layouts/application.html.erb` to just below the `</body>` tag.

When I start the server in development mode and view the source of localhost:3000, I see the javascript below the closing body tag as expected. When I start the server in production mode, however, the javascript appears in its old place, in the `<head>` tag.

Do others have a sense of what might cause this different interpretation of the `app/layouts/application.html.erb` file in development/production environments? Any pointers others can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Ruslan, I'm trying to load js in a script tag after the body tag closes in development and production.

Comment: Clear your cached pages, recompile assets

Comment: Do you use Spring?

Comment: @hjpotter92 You were right, I needed to run `rake tmp:cache:clear`. Strange that the production server itself keeps the cache rather than allowing the client behavior to determine cache holdings. If you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Rails guide on caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html):

> This is an introduction to three types of caching techniques: page,
>   action and fragment caching. By default Rails provides fragment
>   caching. In order to use page and action caching you will need to add
>   `actionpack-page_caching` and `actionpack-action_caching` to your
>   `Gemfile`.
>
> **By default, caching is only enabled in your production environment**. To play around with caching locally you'll want to
>   enable caching in your local environment by setting
>   `config.action_controller.perform_caching` to `true` in the relevant
>   **config/environments/*.rb** file:
>
> ```
> config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
> ```

You just need to clear cached files, as rails caches those by default in production environment.